# PayPal Sandbox | Express checkout allow credit card payments

Tags: php, paypal

First of all a want to mention that I am very new in PayPal at all.

I have create a plugin for WordPress, that is useful for booking a taxi for a trip. The plugin, it has it's own cart, that allowing the client to add several services in the cart and then to check out via PayPal.

As I mentioned earlier I am new, to PayPal, so I have download the PHP SDK provided by the PayPal, and I have complete the first step of the payment process. I have got the Token, and then redirect my client to PayPal web site to perform the payment.

The problem is that, in PayPal web site I have only the options "Have a PayPal account?" and "Create a PayPal account". What I like to ask, is how can I use the credit card payment instead of the "Create a PayPal account" ? Is there any way ?

Any idea please ?

Comment: paypal isn't a CC merchant - you don't pay with a cc. you pay with a paypal account, and then at some later point paypal will charge the CC you registered with

Comment: As I have read in PayPal documentation, in now days you have the ability to use PayPal, in order to checkout with Credit Card too, in Express Checkout. The problem is that I cannot get Credi Card payment in Sandbox.

Comment: @MarcB You do not need a paypal account to pay with a credit card (unless they changed it recently). It's just easier to pay with an account because you have to fill out all your personal information (address/name/credit card ect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try using Stripe. http://www.stripe.com/ super-easy, and has excellent documentation. I have used it alongside Paypal express checkout.

Comment: Looks like is only valid or US and Canada

Answer (score 1):

Paypal now required paypal account to get payment when you use express checkout api, to get payment from paypal use credit card reference api or any other api suit your need from paypal